# How do i hook media queries to screen resolution?

Tags: css, media-queries

I been using queries now for a while and grabbed some pre loaded widths etc depending on what type it will be (Phone, laptop, tablet or even normal screen) and i realized its been using min width and max width and nothing to do with height? So i changed it to max width, max height and now it seems to be conflicting with different screens. So i switched it back to min-width and max width but same issue.

I am completely confused as to how these are meant to be used.. I looked through loads of tutorials and all sorts but i still dont understand correctly. Can someone help me out?

Below is two queries that i put together that conflicts and the reason why i am guessing is due to the max-width being the same?

I changed one to just max-height and still doesnt work so i honestly dont know.

The screen sizes i want to create media queries for is the following:
1280 x 768 and is landscape. I also want to do: 1280 x 720

Media query for screen 1280 x 768:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 768px) 
  and (max-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
{
/*css here*/
}
```

Code for screen 1280 x 720:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 720px) 
  and (max-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
{
/*css here*/
}
```

What did i try?

I tried doing the following which failed:

```
@media only screen 
 and (max-height: 720px) 
 and (orientation: landscape) 
{
 /*Screen 1280 x 720*/
}



@media only screen 
and (max-width: 1280px) 
and (orientation: landscape) 
{
 /*Screen 1280 x 768*/
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I tried matching height by width so max-width: 1280 and max-height: 768 lets say and same for the other res but also no look.. It seems like the screen "1280 x 768" picks up the css for the screen "1280 x 720"

All helps appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If you want to target a specific resolution then why do you use min / max? Moreover screen size is `device-width`.

Comment: The `min-width: 720px` requirement is obviously also satisfied on 1280x768 screens, which is when both of your first two media queries will apply. Which practical problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @zeroflagL There's good reason not to make use of `device-width` in media queries.

Comment: unless you're using sizes based on viewport heights (100vh for example), you shouldn't really need height rules, since a page usually scrolls down as much as it needs... what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @connexo Nobody questioned that. But the OP wrote screen size and `width` does not refer to the screen size, unless the UA runs in full screen mode. There are legitimate reasons to use `device-width` btw.

Comment: @zeroflagL then how would you do this with what i got? Im interested in if it will work.

Comment: Just `(height: 720px)  and (width: 1280px)`, **IF** your application runs fullscreen and you really want to target exactly 1280*720. `device-width/height` if not fullscreen.

Comment: Tried it there, as soon as i switch them to that. It picks up the 1280 x 720 for both.

Comment: `width` and `height` are mutually exclusive properties, any device can have a width with any height, just because the width is xxx doesn't mean the height is constrained at all. Therefore simply use one dimension rather than two for `@media` comparisons. All width or all height. (You can still use the orientation rule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some strange reason it was picking up both queries so i just made it work for both by making whatever smaller to fit both no matter what the size was.

Example:

```
background-color: red;
height: 500px; // I want this for one red and 1200 for another lets say
```

If i make height 1200 it blows it out of proportion but anyway all i did was lets say, leave it as 300px height and was grand. (Not the best, but ok).

If anyone does have a solution then please do let me know as so far this is the only way and is not the best (obviously) solution due to the fact of using only one media query.

Comment: If this is not a solution this shold be an edit to your original question rather than an answer

Answer (score 3):

Your first rule is contradicting your second rule.

1280px x 768 is the same as w x h. So the height would be 768, not the min-width - but this isn't necessary.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-height: 720px) 
  and (max-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
{
/*css here*/
}
```

(you could use max-height here)

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-height: 768px) 
  and (max-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
{
/*css here*/
}
```

Comment: I tried using this and nothing was getting set. I changed the last one to max height like you said and then that one worked but as for the 1280 x 768 on min height doesnt work.